# Save datagridview to mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a datagridview that i wanto to save into mysql database.
I´m able to insert the first row but after that it gives me an error

> "MySql.Data.MySqlCliente.MySqlException
>   (0x80004005):Parameter'@cod' has already been defined)...."

```
try
{
    string config = "server=localhost; userid = root; database = dbName";
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(config);
    string query = "INSERT INTO infoplu(cod,sec,fam,nr) VALUES (@cod,@sec,@fam,@nr)";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();

    for (int row = 0; row < dgExcelData.Rows.Count; row++)
    {                    
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@cod", dgExcelData.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@sec", dgExcelData.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@fam", dgExcelData.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@nr", dgExcelData.Rows[row].Cells[6].Value.ToString());

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("sucess");
    }

    con.Close();
}
catch (MySqlException er)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error:" + er.ToString());
}
```

Can anyone understand this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear()
```

That should be what you need. The error is caused by adding a parameter that already exists.

Call this before adding the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Because every loop in your `for` statement, you try yo add exact same parameters which you have added to your `MySqlCommand` already.

As an alternative, you might need to clear your parameters using [`SqlParameterCollection.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
for (int row = 0; row < dgExcelData.Rows.Count; row++)
{                   
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", dgExcelData.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sec", dgExcelData.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam", dgExcelData.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nr", dgExcelData.Rows[row].Cells[6].Value.ToString());

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   cmd.Parameters.Clear();
   MessageBox.Show("sucess");
}
```

at the end of your `for` loop or you might need to create new `MySqlCommand` top of your `for` loop like;

```
for (int row = 0; row < dgExcelData.Rows.Count; row++)
{  
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);                  
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", dgExcelData.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sec", dgExcelData.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam", dgExcelData.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nr", dgExcelData.Rows[row].Cells[6].Value.ToString());

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   MessageBox.Show("sucess");
}
```

Comment: This is another way of doing it, I wonder if it's more efficient

Comment: @CodeBlend I have no idea. I never measure it. _Actually_, I don't care. Using `Clear()` seems much more clear.